# Вывести данные с базы данных на jsp страницу

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp, servlet

Изучаю java ee, пишу простой блог.
Надо на главную страницу вывести список всех записей.
Есть структура в бд:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `blogentry`;
 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 ;
CREATE TABLE `blogentry` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `subtype` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `show` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `content` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

LOCK TABLES `blogentry` WRITE;
INSERT INTO `blogentry` VALUES (1,'car','bmv',1,'bmv_name1','hello word'),(2,'car','bmv',1,'bmv_name2','hello word'),(3,'car','wv',1,'wv_name1','hello word'),(4,'car','wv',1,'wv_name2','hello word'),(5,'home','myhome',1,'myhomename_1','hello word'),(6,'home','myhome',1,'myhomename_2','hello word');
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

На главной надо получить такой список:

- car

bmv

- bmv_name1
- bmv_name2

wv

- wv_name1
- wv_name2

-home

- myhomename_1
- myhomename_2

*Как это лучше реализовать?*

Пока сделал так:

**Получаем данные с бд:**

```
public class DBBlogEntry {

    public DBBlogEntry() {

    }

    public static ArrayList<String> getTypes(Connection connection) throws SQLException{
        ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<>();
        String sql = "select type from `blogentry`";

        PreparedStatement pstm = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

        ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            String type = rs.getString("type");
            if(!s.contains(type)){
                s.add(type);
            }

        }       
        return s;       
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> getSubTypes(Connection connection, String type) throws SQLException{
        ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<>();
        String sql = "select subtype from `blogentry` where type = ?";

        PreparedStatement pstm = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstm.setString(1, type);

        ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            String subType = rs.getString("subtype");
            if(!s.contains(subType)){
                s.add(subType);
            }

        }       
        return s;       
    }   

    public static ArrayList<String> getName(Connection connection, String type, String subType) throws SQLException{
        ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<>();
        String sql = "select name from `blogentry` where type = ? and `subType` = ?";

        PreparedStatement pstm = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstm.setString(1, type);
        pstm.setString(2, subType);

        ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            String name = rs.getString("name");
            if(!s.contains(name)){
                s.add(name);
            }

        }       
        return s;       
    }       

}


public class BlogEntryWork {

    public BlogEntryWork() {

    }

    public ArrayList<String> getTypes(Connection connection){
        ArrayList<String> s = null;

        try {
            s = DBBlogEntry.getTypes(connection);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return s;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getSubTypes(Connection connection, String type){
        ArrayList<String> s = null;

        try {
            s = DBBlogEntry.getSubTypes(connection, type);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return s;
    }   

    public ArrayList<String> getName(Connection connection, String type, String subType){
        ArrayList<String> s = null;

        try {
            s = DBBlogEntry.getName(connection, type, subType);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return s;
    }       

}


package core.bean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import core.blogentry.BlogEntryWork;

public class Catalogue implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5142442584186727865L;

    private BlogEntryWork entryWork;
    private Connection connection;  

    public Catalogue(Connection connection){
        entryWork = new BlogEntryWork();
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    // получить типы 
    public ArrayList<String> getTypes() {
        return entryWork.getTypes(connection);
    }

    // получить подтипы 
    public ArrayList<String> getSubTypes(String type) {
        return entryWork.getSubTypes(connection, type);
    }

    // получаем имена все записей
    public ArrayList<String> getName(String type, String subType) {
        return entryWork.getName(connection, type, subType);
    }   
}
```

**В сервлете:**

```
request.setAttribute("catalogue", new Catalogue(user.getConnectionDb()));
```

**В jsp:**

```
  <ul>
                <%@ page import="core.bean.*"%>

                <%
                    Catalogue cataloque = (Catalogue) request.getAttribute("catalogue");

                    for (String a : cataloque.getTypes()) {
                        out.println("<li>");
                        out.println(a);
                        out.println("<ul>");
                        for (String b : cataloque.getSubTypes(a)) {
                            out.println("<li>" + b + "</li>");
                            out.println("<ul>");
                            for (String c : cataloque.getName(a, b)) {
                                out.println("<p><a href=\"" + request.getContextPath() + "?entry=" + c + "\">" + c + "</a></p>");
                            }
                            out.println("</ul>");
                        }
                        out.println("</ul>");
                        out.println("</li>");
                    }
                %>
            </ul>
```